# How to return a 404 for just Django allauth signup page?

Tags: django, django-urls, django-allauth

I am rather new to Django and all of the work I have done so far has been with models/views/viewsets.. The site I am working on incorporates Django allauth for authentication. I have successfully edited/styled the login/logout templates, but the page will be accessed by people who are given credentials created in the admin section rather than signing up on their own- so the sign up page is unnecessary. I'd like to just show a 404 page anytime someone lands on the signup page. I have already removed all the links to the signup page from the other templates.

In short- how do I just redirect someone to the Django default page_not_found when they hit /accounts/signup/?

My attempts so far have revolved around editing the URLs.py file to include something like `path('account_signup', page_not_found)` (after importing it at the top), or some other manipulation of that line. I'm probably missing something really easy, as I have been getting a little frustrated... And I haven't found any stack overflows where someone was desiring a 404 when a user navigated to one of the allauth account pages.

Comment: I'm a noob and forgot that python files (urls.py) will evaluate line by line, and I listed `path('accounts/signup/', page_not_found)` after I listed `path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls'))` so it was finding the default path entry rather than mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to server 404 pages automatically for not found url, create a 404 view and then in main projects urls.py have below code
[Read the Official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/views/)

```
handler404 = 'mysite.views.my_custom_page_not_found_view'
```

For redirecting use [Redirect View in django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/base/#redirectview)

```
from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView
    url('/accounts/signup/', RedirectView.as_view(url='/', permanent=False),name='index')
```

Note their is 404 page for developers builts in django, but once you turn debug=False in settings for production apps,it is not visible,

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I had already read through all of that and made a 404 view really quick.  I still wasn't hitting my 404 view though because I was listing it on the bottom of the path list, and django was finding the default path entry from `path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls'))` before it reached mine.  Noob move, I knew it was going to be something silly. I selected this as best answer because it includes links and code samples.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply not use the signup page in your urls.

On the other hand, it is bad practice to use createsuperuser to create users, since by default they will have enough privileges, even to log in to admin and edit things. The right thing to do is to create a user with some method you want, and with the permissions you give them.

This last one will allow you to use a decorator in your signup view that only allows access to that page in case you have an account with a particular privilege, and not any user. There is no point in returning a 404.

Comment: I think "not using the signup page in my urls" would mean that I would have to make an individual path entry for each of the allauth pages I did want? That is another way to do it probably.